# Amazon web services and UWP with xamarin.forms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, uwp, amazon-cognito, xamarin.uwp

I implemented aws cognito identity and sync into my xamarin.forms project. everything works fine on android. I wanted to give it a try on uwp application. Instantly I got an exception as below. Does it mean that AWS doesnt support Pcl implementation but it should be naively implemented and referenced with dependency injection?

```
    AWSSDK.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

    Additional information: This functionality is not implemented in the
 portable version of this assembly.

     You should reference the AWSSDK.Core NuGet package from your main 
application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
```

I have following nugets installed for both uwp and XF projects

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instantly I got an exception as below.

Nuget installs different versions of dlls when you are adding the nuget package.(You can find them under `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\AWSSDK.Core\<version>\lib`). And depends on your project type, nuget decides, which dll should be referenced for your project. From the error message, the functionality you are currently using is not included in the portable version dll.

> Does it mean that AWS doesnt support Pcl implementation but it should be naively implemented and referenced with dependency injection?

Yes. Since the Pcl version dll doesn't hold this functionality, you need to implemented it natively with dependency injection.

Comment: This is another disappointment with AWS. I read through their entire documentation for xamarin and nowhere in their docu, they highlight that PCL doesnt support UWP and WP8.1.